# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected global [APPUSER]

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, drools-guvnor

We are using rule engine in our application using below the drools related dependencies

```html
<properties>
<runtime.version>7.60.0.Final</runtime.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
  <version>${runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>${runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
  <version>${runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
  <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
  <version>${runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-bpmn2</artifactId>
  <version>${runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-flow</artifactId>
  <version>${runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-flow-builder</artifactId>
  <version>${runtime.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

```html
Private void updateUserAccessFunction(User user) throws UserException {
 KieSession skieSession = RuleFactory.INSTANCE.CreateKieSession();
  skieSession.setGlobal("APPUSER",false);
  skieSession.insert(user);
  Map<String,Obejct> data = new HashMap<String,Object>();
   data.put("user",user);
   skieSession.startProcess("userenrichmentrules",user);
}

userFunctions.drl
global Boolean APPUSER;
```

Facing Vulnerabilities issues with 7.9.0.Final version so we are upgrading 7.60.0.Final version,while calling the rules part getting below error,

i can see the global variable AppUser in drl file.

global Boolean AppUser;

This error occurs when I try to set a global variable in KieSession Seeing the method StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl#setGlobal(String, Object) seems that I should set the globals before create a newInstance

why it is not picking my global variable? or i need to set the global varibale is any other way?

ERROR:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected global [AppUser]

Please help me to resolve it

TIA

Comment: Please add your actual code where you set your global on the session before firing the rules. Also an example of your DRL.

Comment: Hi Roddy, i added the actual code where we are setting the global on the session.

Comment: hi, any news on this? I am facing the same problem. i want to set a backend service as a global variable, that the rule can use it if they want.
But getting the same error.